# Php exec command return an empty array for convert image file

Tags: php

```
exec(convert 'E:/wamp/www/solvexis/uploads/course/hadoop.jpg' -colorspace RGB -resize 150X150\> -strip -gravity Center 'E:/wamp/www/solvexis/cache/0fbdec280320f6bdb4a25352bde06b20_150.jpg'",$output);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Empty array returns.

Comment: This is a PHP question because?  What happens when you run `convert 'E:/wamp/www/solvexis/uploads/course/hadoop.jpg' -colorspace RGB -resize 150X150> -strip -gravity Center 'E:/wamp/www/solvexis/cache/0fbdec280320f6bdb4a25352bde06b20_150.jpg` from the command line?

Comment: You need quotes arount the first argument to `exec()`. You should be getting a syntax error because of the missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

Like Barmar noted in his comments: "Your Commands should be enclosed in Quotes..." The First Parameter of the exec Command should be a String. So your Code should have read something like this:

```
<?php


        exec("convert " . 'E:/wamp/www/solvexis/uploads/course/hadoop.jpg ' . "-colorspace RGB -resize 150X150\> -strip -gravity Center 'E:/wamp/www/solvexis/cache/0fbdec280320f6bdb4a25352bde06b20_150.jpg'",$output);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($output);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
```

Comment: Hi barmar thanks for your reply. Actually i had used this quotation in my code , I'm just forget to show here. And still its not showing any results. I have used whoami command its work perfectly on my code.